# Dive into implementation of updateConstraints() method

Tags: snapkit

There's one question: should I call `setNeedsLayout()` & `layoutIfNeeded()` after calling `<view>.snp.updateConstraints()` method?

Or the implementation of `updateConstraints()` by default makes it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary. You can just call `updateConstraints()`

About **setNeedsLayout()** & **layoutIfNeeded()** you can read here: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/ios-swift-setneedslayout-vs-layoutifneeded-vs-layoutsubviews-5a2b486da31c